# Unpoly | Exclude empty form fields from submitted values

Tags: javascript, unpoly

I'm trying to build a search form which has some inputs with attribute `up-autosubmit`, so the form is submitted dynamically by `Unpoly`. But there are some text fields in the form which may not be filled by user and I'd like empty fields not to be sent because the form method is `get` and all such fields spoil the query string.

I tried to clean them like this:

```
up.on('up:form:submit', function(ev) {
    let form = ev.target
    if (form.classList.contains('search-form')) {
        let textInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
        for (let i = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
            if (textInputs[i].value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
                textInputs[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
            }
        }
    }
})

up.compiler('.search-results-wrap', function(el) {
    let textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.search-form input[type=text]')
    for (let i = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
        textInputs[i].removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
})
```

But it didn't work.

What's the way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the form was submitted when any checkbox in the form was clicked and all checkboxes are provided with up-autosubmit attribute for Unpoly make the job done. I tried to make a callback on native submit event but it was never called. 
The only approach which worked for me is to set a callback on checkbox inputs change event:

```
up.compiler('form.search-form input[type=checkbox]', function(ch) {
    ch.addEventListener('change', function() {
        let form = ch.form
        let textInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
        for (let i = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
            if (textInputs[i].value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
                textInputs[i].setAttribute('disabled', true)
            }
        }
        setTimeout(0, function() {
            let textInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
            for (let i = 0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
                if (textInputs[i].value.match(/^\s*$/)) {
                    textInputs[i].removeAttribute('disabled')
                }
            }            
        })        
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach didn't work because at the time `up:form:submit` is emitted the form params are already parsed.

In the next major version the `up:form:submit` event will have an `event.options.params` property that event handlers can manipulate.

A workaround would be to bind to the vanilla `submit` event and manipulate the form before Unpoly parses values:

```
up.compiler('form.search-form', function(form) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    disableEmptyInputs(form)
  })
})
```

Comment: This didn't work, I tried but on submit callback is never called, I suppose that unpoly prevents it from being called. Tried this: up.compiler('form.search-form', function(form) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    console.log("form is submitted")
  })
})